# Next js payload cms environment variable do not read from .env

Tags: next.js

`PAYLOAD_SECRET` is missing for payload cms:

```
import path from "path";
import type { InitOptions } from "payload/config";
import payload from "payload";
dotenv.config({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./.env"),
});
let cached = (global as any).payload;
if (!cached) {
  cached = (global as any).payload = {
    client: null,
    promise: null,
  };
}
interface Args {
  initOptions?: Partial<InitOptions>;
}
export const getPayloadClient = async ({ initOptions }: Args) => {
  if(!process.env.PAYLOAD_SECRET) {
    throw new Error("PAYLOAD_SECRET is missing")
  }

  if (cached.client) {
    return cached.client
  }

  if (cached.promise) {
    cached.promise = payload.init({
      secret: process.env.PAYLOAD_SECRET,
      local: initOptions?.express ? false : true,
      ...(initOptions|| {}),
    })
  }

  try {
    cached.client = await cached.promise
  } catch (e: unknown) {
    cached.promise = null
    throw e
  }

  return cached.client
};
```

```
PAYLOAD_SECRET=mysecret
NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:3000
MONGODB_URL=mongodb+srv:
```

The error is:

> Error: PAYLOAD_SECRET is missing

I do not know about next js to much any help!

I tried everything, but do not want run I try delete `node_modules` and reinstall it with `npm install` but don't

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change `PAYLOAD_SECRET` to `NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYLOAD_SECRET`?

Adding the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix to environment variables helps Next.js to read those variables from the browser.

References: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the PAYLOAD_SECRET to a string greater than 14 characters
for example

```
PAYLOAD_SECRET = bwuiyr9483urbfw894yh9iu
```

Also be sure to include

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
```